# how to get first 4 characters of a string and convert to uppercase and add number with 6 digit format?

Tags: php, mysql, string, phpmyadmin

I have MySQL table with id,code,branch column. id column is auto generate with auto increment.

in code column i want to generate and save as follows:

a) first 4 character of Branch field in uppercase.
+
b) 6 digit number, it will generate the next value of last id.

format like, if branch is kolkata,and last id is 1 then - KOLK000002

how to build this?

Comment: Do you need the code to zero-pad the ID to ensure 6 characters?  What happens when you have more than 999,999 records?

Comment: data not more than 999 999

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have the last ID? Something like this should work.

```
$str = strtoupper(substr($branch, 0, 4)) . ($lastID + 1);
```

Comment: let i have added first row with 1 in id field

Comment: Typo, should be `strtoupper(substr($branch,0,4)) . ($lastID + 1)`

Comment: how about the prefix of last id?

Comment: @BikashMahata you're asking how to prefix with zeros???  `while( strlen($lastID) < 6 ) { $lastID= '0'.$lastID; }`.  Do this AFTER you increment by 1.